# how to change inline style in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 images" data-columns="5" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
```

I want to change the opacity to 1

I tried using this in additional css

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 images{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have access to modify wordpress or plugin code that generates the inline style, you can override it with `!important`.

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5.images{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

This declaration will have higher precedence than the inline style, and will be applied.

Find out more about `!important` and specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Comment: I've fixed the selector as well. To target elements with multiple classes, the correct selector would be `.classOne.classTwo.classThree...` - note the dot before each class name and no space between them.